# Mediawiki: How to permantly move the location of the table of contents

Tags: css, mediawiki, wikipedia, tableofcontents

As it stands, mediawiki automatically places the Table of contents after the first paragraph. Where do I go to change that placement to say the beginning of the article, or above the infobox, or anything like that?

I ask because I'm using a new skin and the placement of the TOC is not aesthetically pleasing so I'm trying to move it. If I can understand how to move it in a regular skin, I'd be able to figure out how to move it there.

Answer (score 0):

The magic word `__TOC__` will place the table of contents wherever you write it in the article. (If you have multiple `__TOC__`'s, the first one will be used.

Also, I'm flagging flagging this as off topic, as not programming related. If you are trying to write an extension to implement a different logic for TOC placement, please come back here when you get stuck!